# How do we Access Java Restful Web services session variables in HTML5 & javascript

Tags: java, rest, session

I'm working on Hybrid Mobile app development. I have developed RESTful web services in java and I need to get that session value in my HTML page i.e client side. How do we maintain session in javascript?.

Here is my restful webservice

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;

@GET
@Path("session")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public String session(@QueryParam("lname") String name1) {
    String response2 = null;
    String name11 = "kheerthi";
    try {

        // Jdbc Connection
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int cols = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        while (rs.next()) {
            if (rs.getString(1) != "null") {
                request.getSession(true);
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("name", "value");
                session.setAttribute("UserName", rs.getString(2));
                String username = (String) session.getAttribute("UserName");
                System.out.println(username);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "fail";
}
```

Here is my frontend code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn4").click(function() {
        alert("Button Clicked");
        $lname = $("#lname").val();
        alert("function called1");
        alert($lname);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/samplerestful_demo/webresources/generic/session',
            data: {lname: $lname},
            type: 'GET',
            crossDomain: true,
            ContentType: 'html/text',
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false
        }).done(function(response) {
           if (response == 'success') {
              // var value = '@Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["UserName"]';
               window.location.replace("http://localhost:8383/HTML5Application1/listform.html");
            }
            else {
                alert("else called");
                 window.location.replace("http://localhost:8383/HTML5Application1/login1.html");
            }
        }).fail(function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + " : " + errorThrown.toString());
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: If any, what specific error is being thrown here? Whats happening that shouldn't be happening? be more descriptive than "How do we maintain session in javascript?"

Comment: @doveyg problem is like RESTful web service in server side and we are calling that restful web service in client side that to frontend technologies(Hybrid mobileapp).

Comment: There's nothing problematic with that statement. Seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: probelm is like how do we main session in javascript. HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("name", "value");
                session.setAttribute("UserName", rs.getString(2)); how do we get this session value in javascript.

Comment: @doveyg Here RESTful web service is java application and HTML coding is another HTML application. We can call that restful URL using ajax and how do we maintain session in HTML application.

Comment: So, your question is "how do I get data back from an AJAX request using jQuery?". What have you tried? What were your obstacles? Have you had a look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)?

Comment: @doveyg Exactly, How do we get data from restful web service using AJAX?. How we will maintain that data on jQuery or javascript?.

Comment: @doveyg  Here is RESTful code request.getSession(true);
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("name", "value");
                session.setAttribute("UserName", rs.getString(2));

Comment: @doveyg We can call generally in java using session.getAttribute("UserName"); But here it is AJAX and jQuery. This is what problem is.